# not fetching the correct values from database based on where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I am trying to run a query in codeigniter. There are 3 values that are being fetched from the frontend, these 3 values are

```
$location
$min_exp
$max_exp
```

if there is a value inside it then it needs to get included in where condition, so i created a query like this for all 3 values

```
if($location)
    {
       $this->db->where('location', $location );
    }

if($min_exp)
    {
      $this->db->where('experience >= ', $min_exp );
    }

if($max_exp)
    {
      $this->db->where('experience <= ', $max_exp );
    }

$data1 = $this->db->get('tablename');
$first_array[] = $data1->result_array();
echo $this->db->last_query();

SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `location` = 'USA' AND `experience` >= '4' AND `experience` <= '10'
```

but this query is not fetching the result based on the condition   and when i try to execute the query in phpmyadmin there also it displays all the data.

Can anyone please tell where i am going wrong and how i need to correct it

Comment: Where location <= 'usa' seems unusual. I would imagine you want where location = 'usa'

Comment: @LJ01 the location was an error, i have updated it

Comment: @sammy     what u get in $first_array[]?

Comment: @Mohit Kumar i am getting all the rows of the table

Comment: then what u want in it?

Comment: @Mohit Kumar i want only that data should come where the condition of "where" is fullfilled

Comment: your if block is what returns ? is it make correct sql query for you?

Comment: @Mohit Kumar  yes it is correct for me

Comment: So are there any records that should be filtered out? Some examples of your data, what the query produces and what you expect you query to produce will probably be required for anyone to be off more assistance...

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause should probably look like this:

```
WHERE `location` = 'USA' AND
       `experience` >= 4 AND `experience` <= 10
```

Note the equality for `location` and the lack of single quotes for `experience`.

Comment: I am writing the code in CodeIgniter, and this where the query is getting generated through it so i am not able to do anything regarding the quotes

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all `if()` conditions have not any value so query giving you all the records.

First check all the variables having value or not

```
if(!empty($location))
{
  var_dump($location); //OR
  print_r($location); 
}
```

If all variables have not value then all rows will return otherwise `WHERE` condition will apply